# Simpler way of sorting three numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

Is there a simpler and better way to solve this problem because

1. I used too many variables.
2. I used so many `if else` statements
3. I did this using the brute force method

> Write a program that receives three integers as input and outputs the numbers in increasing order.
>   Do not use loop / array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
   int no1;
   int no2;
   int no3;
   int sto;
   int hi;
   int lo;

   printf("Enter No. 1: ");
   scanf("%d", &no1);
   printf("Enter No. 2: ");
   scanf("%d", &no2);         
   printf("Enter No. 3: ");
   scanf("%d", &no3);

   if (no1>no2) {   
      sto=no1;    
      lo=no2;   
   } else {
      sto=no2;  
      lo=no1;  
   } 
   if (sto>no3) { 
      hi=sto;    
      if(lo>no3){         
         sto=lo;                
         lo=no3;
      }else {
         sto=no3;      
      }         
   }else hi=no3; 

   printf("LOWEST %d\n", lo);
   printf("MIDDLE %d\n", sto);
   printf("HIGHEST %d\n", hi);  

   getch(); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a much better way, but you need to use loops and arrays. Probably, for an introductory class, your answer is the answer they are looking for. There are ways to get looping with for/while (recursion, goto, etc). And ways to get something like an array without indexing (`int *ptr = malloc (3 * sizeof(int))`, and then index with `*(ptr+index)`). But, I find it hard to think that that's what they want.

Comment: Hint: if you have 3 numbers, a, b, and c, min(a, min(b, c)) is the smallest, max(a, max(b, c)) is the largest, and given the smallest and largest numbers, it should be easy to find the third one.

Comment: Related post - [Sorting 3 numbers without branching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8098146/465053)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
if (a > c)
   swap(a, c);

if (a > b)
   swap(a, b);

//Now the smallest element is the 1st one. Just check the 2nd and 3rd

if (b > c)
   swap(b, c);
```

> Note: Swap changes the values of two
>   variables.

Comment: This should explain why the solution is valid as well; i.e. talk about sorting networks in some way.

Answer (score 11):

Call the three variables `x`, `y`, and `z`, then:

```
if (x > y) swap(x, y);
if (y > z) swap(y, z)
if (x > y) swap(x, y);
```

Writing the `swap` function is left as an exercise for the reader. Hint: you may have to use pointers.

Comment: How about you don't leave it as an exercise for the reader and provide a full solution? Also how about you explain why this is a valid solution (sorting network) instead of just posting it?

Answer (score 10):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define min(a,b) ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
int main(){
   int a, b, c;
   int hi;
   int lo;

   printf("Enter No. 1: ");
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("Enter No. 2: ");
   scanf("%d", &b);         
   printf("Enter No. 3: ");
   scanf("%d", &c);

   lo = min(min(a, b), c);
   hi = max(max(a, b), c);
   printf("LOWEST %d\n", lo);
   printf("MIDDLE %d\n", a+b+c-lo-hi);
   printf("HIGHEST %d\n", hi);  

   getchar(); 
}
```

Comment: Mathematically a+b+c-lo-hi is correct but computationally it might give us an overflow. So the swap version is more safe.

Comment: Why using MACROs instead of regular functions?

Comment: Jarod42, why not?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to sort the values into new external variables, you can actually do the swaps without temporaries:

```
void sort(int a, int b, int c, int *min, int *mid, int *max) {
    min = a;
    mid = b;
    max = c;
    if (min > mid) { mid = a; min = b; }
    if (mid > max)
    {
        max = mid;
        mid = c;
        if (min > mid)
        {
            mid = min;
            min = c;
        }
    }
}
```

This works because the last swap test is really only needed if the second test succeeds (otherwise it will simply be a repetition of the first test, which will fail by definition since we already sorted those variables).

Because of this, we can track the assignments of each of the original variables and avoid swap locals.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  //Temporary storage variable
  int t = 0;

  printf("Enter No. a: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("Enter No. b: ");
  scanf("%d", &b);         
  printf("Enter No. c: ");
  scanf("%d", &c);

  if (a > b) 
  {   
      t = a;    
      a = b;
      b = t;
  }
  if (a > c)
  {
    t = a;
    a = c;
    c = t;
  }
  if (c < b)
  {
    t = c;
    c = b;
    b = t;
  }
  
  printf("a = %d < b = %d < c = %d", a, b, c);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 1):

To find the *min*, *mid* and *max* of 3 values, you can use the *ternary* operator. You can either do all your work within the main body of your code, or you can separate the `minof3`, `midof3` and `maxof3` calculations into reusable functions.

In the case of *min* and *max* you simply make 2 out of 3 possible comparisons, and then return a comparison of the results. In the case of *mid*, you do the same, but compute the min and max of the 3 values, and then check all 3 against *min* and *max* in order to find the value that is neither the *min* or *max*. (you can do this part in the main body of your code without an additional function by declaring the min and max values as variables and doing the elimination there).

Putting the pieces together, you could do something similar to the following, which takes the first 3 arguments as the values to sort (or uses defaults of `99, 231, 8` if a needed value isn't specified)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/** direct ternary comparison of 3 values */
long minof3 (long a, long b, long c) {
    long x = a < b ? a : b,
         y = a < c ? a : c;
    return x < y ? x : y;
}

long maxof3 (long a, long b, long c) {
    long x = a > b ? a : b,
         y = a > c ? a : c;
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

long midof3 (long a, long b, long c) {
    long x = a < b ? a : b,
         y = a > b ? a : b,
         z = y < c ? y : c;
    return x > z ? x : z;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    long x = argc > 1 ? strtol (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 99,
         y = argc > 2 ? strtol (argv[2], NULL, 10) : 231,
         z = argc > 3 ? strtol (argv[3], NULL, 10) : 8;

    /* strtol validations omitted for brevity */

    printf ("\n sorted values : %ld, %ld, %ld\n",
            minof3 (x, y, z), midof3 (x, y, z), maxof3 (x, y, z));
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sort3
 sorted values : 8, 99, 231

$ ./bin/sort3 -23 -281 1031
 sorted values : -281, -23, 1031
```

(yes, I know this is an old post, but given the recent comment about code hidden behind the `swap` function, a full example was in order).

Answer (score 1):

The following code performs only 2 (best case) to 3 (worst case) conditional tests, with no assignment operations nor any extra variables:

```
void from(int ref, int x, int y) {
    (ref < y) ? ((x < y) ? echo(ref,x,y) : echo(ref,y,x)) : echo(y,ref,x);
}
void printSorted(int a, int b, int c) { (a < b) ? from(a,b,c) : from(b,a,c); }
```

**Basic call** (`scanf()` stuff avoided for simplicity):

```
void echo(int _1st, int _2nd, int _3rd) { printf("%d %d %d", _1st, _2nd, _3rd); }
int main() {
    printSorted(2,3,1); //Output: 1 2 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A compact solution sans *magic* `swap()` function, that dances around `int` overflow, and abuses arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    int c = atoi(argv[3]);

    int ab[] = {a, b}, bc[] = {b, c};
    int smaller[] = {ab[a > b], bc[b > c]}, larger[] = {ab[a < b], bc[b < c]};
    int smallest = smaller[a > c], largest = larger[a < c];
    int middle = (a - smallest) + (b - largest) + c;

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", smallest, middle, largest);

    return 0;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
> ./a.out 2147483647 2147483645 2147483646
2147483645, 2147483646, 2147483647
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution if you are looking to sort only 3 numbers.

```
void orderOfThree(int *a1, int *a2, int *a3){
        
     if (*a1 > *a2){ // 6 4 3
        int temp_number = *a1;
        *a1 = *a2;
        *a2 = temp_number;
     }
     
     if (*a2 > *a3){ // 4 3 6
         int temp_number = *a2;
         *a2 = *a3;
         *a3 = temp_number;
     }
     
     if (*a1 > *a2){ // 3 4 6
        int temp_number = *a1;
        *a1 = *a2;
        *a2 = temp_number;
     }
       
}
```

Feel free to change * pointer arguments with your desired inputs.

Comment: This is essentially a sorting network for three elements. It would be good if the answer explained the theory behind it instead of just providing sample code.

Answer (score 0):

In one of his talks<sup>1</sup>, Walter E. Brown discussed the usage of operator less in many algorithms, also "showing how easy it is to make mistakes when using operator < primitive directly". That was a C++ talk, specifically about the C++ Standard Library, but one the algorithms he showed was precisely a three items sort.

Written in C, the functions he propesed would look like this:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

bool out_of_order(int a, int b) {
  return b < a;
}

bool in_order(int a, int b) {
  return !out_of_order(a, b);
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
  int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

void sort2(int *a ,int *b) {
  if ( out_of_order(*a, *b) )
    swap(a, b);
}

void sort3(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
  sort2(a, b);
  if ( in_order(*b, *c) )
    return;                     // <-- Note the early returns
  swap(b, c);
  if ( in_order(*a, *b) )
    return;                     // <--
  swap(a, b);
}
```

He also mentioned that this is actually a (maybe unfamiliar) implementation of bubble sort<sup>2</sup>.

If you are scared by the multiple function calls, please look at the assembly generated by GCC, compiling with `-O2`:

```
sort3:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        cmp     eax, ecx
        jge     .L8
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
        mov     eax, ecx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], ecx
.L8:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        cmp     ecx, eax
        jge     .L7
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], ecx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        cmp     edx, eax
        jge     .L7
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
.L7:
        ret
```

Compare it with the one generated by the code<sup>3</sup> in the accepted answer:

```
sort_three:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        cmp     eax, ecx
        jle     .L13
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], ecx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
.L13:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        cmp     ecx, eax
        jge     .L14
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], ecx
        mov     ecx, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
.L14:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        cmp     eax, ecx
        jge     .L12
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], ecx
.L12:
        ret
```

Can you spot the differences?

---

<sup>1) There are multiple versions of it:

[Correctly Calculating min, max, and More - Walter E Brown - CPPP 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5EiYmjBS84)

[Walter E. Brown - Correctly calculating min, max and more - Meeting C++ online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1U6AXEgNbE)

[itCppCon21 - Extrema: Correctly Calculating min and max (Walter E Brown)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-TNCbX8mOQ)</sup>

<sup>2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort</sup>

<sup>3) Well, slighlty modified, I had to make those variables pointers: https://godbolt.org/z/9Yn8xEM68</sup>

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a,b,c;
    printf("enter a b c values:\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    if(a<b && a<c)
    {   printf("%d,",a);
        if(b<c)
            printf("%d,%d",b,c);
        else
            printf("%d,%d",c,b);
    }
    else if(b<a && b<c)
    {
        printf("%d,",b);
        if(a<c)
            printf("%d,%d",a,c);
        else
        printf("%d,%d",c,a);
    }
    else
    {
    printf("%d,",c);
    if(a<b)
    printf("%d,%d",a,b);
    else
    printf("%d,%d",b,a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
        int number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int number3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int swap = 0;

        if (number2 > number1 && number2 > number3)
        {
            swap = number2;
            number2 = number1;
            number1 = swap;

        }
        else if (number3 > number2 && number3 > number1)
        {
            swap = number3;
            number3 = number1;
            number1 = swap;
        }
        if (number3 > number2)
        {
            swap = number2;
            number2 = number3;
            number3 = swap;

        }
        Console.WriteLine(number1 + "/" + number2 + "/" + number3);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -3):

I was attempting to solve the same problem today. Could make this compact version of code without using any temporary variables; loops; library functions like swap, sort, max, min, etc. The code uses only if statements and makes continuous mutations in the hierarchy until all possibilities are checked.

```
int main()
{
  int a, b, c; //User inputs stored in these three variables
  int first, second, third; //These three variables will store the sorted numbers in sequence
  std::cout<<"Please enter three integers : "; //User input prompt
  std::cin>>a>>b>>c;

  first = a; //Initially assuming number 'a' is smallest
  if (b <= a && b <= c) first = b; //Checking whether b is smallest
  if (c <= a && c <= b) first = c; //Checking whether c is smallest
  if (((a >= b && a <= c) || (a >= c && a <= b))) second = a; //Checking if a is middle number
  if (((b >= a && b <= c) || (b >= c && b <= a))) second = b; //Checking if b is middle number
  if (((c >= a && c <= b) || (c >= b && b <= a))) second = c; //Checking if c is middle number
  if (a >= b && a >= c) third = a; //Checking if a is the greatest
  if (b >= c && b >= a) third = b; //Checking if b is the greatest
  if (c >= a && c >= b) third = c; //Checking if c is the greatest

  std::cout<<"The numbers in ascending order are : "<<first<<", "<<second<<", "<<third<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is cool but it can hardly be described as "more compact" than OPs version. (Am I missing irony?)