# Sorting 3 numbers without branching

Tags: c#, c++, sorting, integer, branchless

In C# or C++ how can I implement a branch-free sort of three (integer) numbers?

Is this possible?

Comment: Huh? Are these random sentences?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Please show us your best guess.  What do you mean sorting without a condition?

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean, but your sentences are so ill-formed as to be barely understandable.  Try cleaning up your grammar and being somewhat more explicit about what it is you're trying to achieve and you will be more likely to get an answer.  As @MooingDuck said, examples are very helpful.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "without condition".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is, "How to sort 3 integer values without using conditional operators". A more practical version would be "how to write a branch-free sort for 3 values". It certainly does suck around here if you English isn't that great, but I guess the same is true of most international software development.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I agree with your assessment of the question. I've edited it accordingly and voted to reopen.

Comment: Related post - [Simpler way of sorting three numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4367745/465053)

Comment: Note that the assembly might be branchless even if the code looks branching https://godbolt.org/z/e43159zrT

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No conditionals. Only a cast to uint. Perfect solution.

```
int abs (int a) 
{
    int b = a;
    b = (b >> (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1) & 1);
    return 2 * b * (a) + a; 
}
int max (int a, int b) { return (a + b + abs(a - b)) / 2; }
int min (int a, int b) { return (a + b - abs(a - b)) / 2; }


void sort (int & a, int & b, int & c)
{       
   int maxnum = max(max(a,b), c);
   int minnum = min(min(a,b), c);
   int middlenum = a + b + c - maxnum - minnum;
   a = maxnum;
   b = middlenum;
   c = minnum;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because (among other more easily fixable errors) `abs` doesn't return the absolute value of `a`.

Comment: corrected all errors. I don't like relying on knowing the size of an int, but without knowing that, I'd need a while loop, and that's a conditional. Since it does 2 * b first, it's safe. However, if you wanted to make sure, you can add parenthesis around 2 * b

Comment: @Xaade: why not just ask the compiler what the size of an int is :)

Comment: The usual existential doubt applies about the result of `>>` for a negative value. Using C# would probably resolve the issue, it's allowed by the question ;-)

Comment: `b = (b >> (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1) & 1);` has implementation behavior for negative numbers. `2 * b * (a) + a;` should be `2 * b * (-a) + a;` and would have undefined behavior in case of arithmetic overflow. `return (a + b + abs(a - b)) / 2;` potential arithmetic overflow,  same for `int middlenum = a + b + c - maxnum - minnum;`... not really a perfect solution I'm afraid.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in C++ with:

```
#include <iostream>

void sort(int *in) {
  const int sum = in[0]+in[1];
  const int diff = abs(in[1]-in[0]);
  in[0] = (sum + diff) / 2;
  in[1] = (sum - diff) / 2;
}

int main() {
  int a[] = {3,4,1};
  sort(a);
  sort(a+1);
  sort(a);
  std::cout << a[0] << "," << a[1] << "," << a[2] << std::endl;

  int b[] = {1,2,3};
  sort(b);
  sort(b+1);
  sort(b);
  std::cout << b[0] << "," << b[1] << "," << b[2] << std::endl;
}
```

The trick is in expressing the min/max elements as arithmetic operations, not branching and then calling sort on pairs enough times to "bubble sort" them.

---

I've made a totally generic version, using template meta-programming to call `sort` the right number of times. It all gets inlined exactly as you'd hope with gcc 4.7.0 on my x86 box (although `call` is unconditional on x86 anyway). I've also implemented an abs function that avoids branches on x86 (it makes a few assumptions about integers that make it less portable, it's based on gcc's `__builtin_abs` implementation for x86 though):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

void myabs(int& in) {
  const int tmp = in >> ((sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
  in ^= tmp;
  in = tmp - in;
}

template <int N, int I=1, bool C=false>
struct sorter {
  static void sort(int *in) {
    const int sum = in[I-0]+in[I-1];
    int diff = in[I-1]-in[I-0];
    myabs(diff);
    in[I-0] = (sum + diff) / 2;
    in[I-1] = (sum - diff) / 2;
    sorter<N, I+1, I+1>=N>::sort(in);
  }
};

template <int N,int I>
struct sorter<N,I,true> {
  static void sort(int *in) {
    sorter<N-1>::sort(in);
  }
};

template <int I, bool C>
struct sorter<0,I,C> {
  static void sort(int *) {
  }
};

int main() {
  int a[] = {3,4,1};
  sorter<3>::sort(a);
  std::cout << a[0] << "," << a[1] << "," << a[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Two swaps aren't sufficient to bring all of the 6 permutations in the correct order. For example, `1 2 3` is "sorted" into `2 3 1`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default implementation of abs branches, but you can avoid the branch by just hex ANDing to remove the bit for negativity. Also depending on whether the OP considers a function call to be a branch you might want to explicitly inline the method. But those are trivial - good answer!

Comment: @FredOverflow - you're right, I've fixed that by adding the extra swap.

Comment: @Dracorat - I added another version which includes `myabs` which is branch free. (GCC was doing it like that anyway under the covers though). Calling a function is unconditional and so can't really be considered branching.

Comment: Well, I can't +1 your code more than once =)

Answer (score 7):

You can write `max`, `min` and `swap` branch-free functions. Once you have these functions, you can use them to write `sort` function as:

```
void sort(int &a, int &b, int &c)
{
    int m1 = max(a,b,c);
    int m2 = min(a,b,c);
    b = a + b + c - m1 - m2;
    swap(m1, a);
    swap(m2, c);
}
```

And here are the helper functions:

```
void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
   int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;
}

int max( int a, int b, int c ) {
   int l1[] = { a, b };
   int l2[] = { l1[ a<b ], c };
   return l2[ l2[0] < c ];
}
int min( int a, int b, int c ) {
   int l1[] = { a, b };
   int l2[] = { l1[ a>b ], c };
   return l2[ l2[0] > c ];
}
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
        int a,b,c;
        std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
        sort(a,b,c);
        std::cout << a <<"," << b << "," << c << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
21 242 434
```

Output (descending order):

```
434, 242, 21
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/3ZOzc

I have taken the implementation of `max` from @David's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074010/find-maximum-of-three-number-in-c-without-using-conditional-statement-and-ternar/7186810#7186810), and implemented `min` with little twist.

Comment: on x86 that will become branch statements, the < and && are both implemented as such

Comment: @awoodland: Not really. Just compile that with optimizations.

Comment: it really does, for example with `g++ -O4 -S` (4.7.0) min has two `jle` instructions and max has two `jge` instructions which are both looking at the results of `cmpl`s

Comment: The answer you cited is incorrect `cmpl` followed by a `cmovg` *is* a branch. `cmovge` reads the condition codes from the `cmpl` and the code after it does depend on the result before. Looking at condition codes is the very definition of branching.

Comment: @awoodland: Alright. I changed my solution, taking David's implementation of `max`.

Comment: You're gonna hate me for this, but there's still a branch with maximum optimizations (`jle` and `jge`) from the `>` and `<` operators. Like this you can get it to become `seta` with a bit of fiddling, but that's also a branch still.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with additions, is that they can overflow.

You can do it with `XOR` products, which do not overflow.

This works, because the `XOR` product is associative, commutative, and is his own inverse:

`a = (a ^ b) ^ b`

```
(int min, int middle, int max) Sort_3_numbers(int a, int b, int c)
{
    // Calculate the XOR of all values
    int all = a ^ b ^ c;// This will be calculated in parallel by out of order cpu

    // Find the minimum and maximum values 
    int _min = min(min(a, b), c);
    int _max = max(max(a, b), c);    

    // Extract the middle value
    int middle = all ^ _min ^ _max;

    return (_min, middle, _max);
}
```