# How can I access an array created in another function in main without returning it?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

First post on StackOverflow. I'm supposed to create a function:

```
int sumsort(int *a, int *b, int *c)
```

This function should arrange the 3 values in the memory locations pointed to
by a, b, and c in ascending order and also return the sum of the contents of
the memory locations a, b, and c.

Here's my function:

```
 int sumsort(int *a, int *b, int *c) {

    int sum = *a + *b + *c;

    int sorted[] = {*a, *b, *c};

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

       if (sorted[0] > sorted[1]) 

       {
          int temp = sorted[1];
          sorted[1] = sorted[0];
          sorted[0] = temp;
       } // end if
       if (sorted[1] > sorted[2]) 
       {
          int temp2 = sorted[2];
          sorted[2] = sorted[1];
          sorted[1] = temp2;
       } // end if

    } // end for

    return sum;

} // end sumsort function
```

How can I access the `sorted[]` array in main? I need to print the 3 variables in ascending order but don't really see how I can do that since the `sumsort` function has to return the sum and the actual sorting has to happen in the `sumsort` function too.

I tried creating a new array variable in main and assigning it `sorted[]` after I call the `sumsort` function, but that doesn't work because it's out of scope?

Comment: You are not allowed to change the signature of `sumsort`? You can't give it a 4th argument?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Make an array of *pointers* and sort that array according to indirect values

Comment: Your task is to *swap the contents* of `*a`, `*b` and `*c`. Not creating a new structure which would reference them in order as you did, but simply swapping them.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you cannot access your `sorted` variable from `main`. But you don't need to. The point of the function is that it modifies the values pointed by its parameters.

For instance:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5, y = 1, z = 3;

    int sum = sumsort(&x, &y, &y);

    // now  x == 1  ,  y == 3  , z == 5
}
```

This is possible. Inside `sumsort` you need not to create a new array, but to modify the values pointed by it's paramters.

For instance, if you had to sort just two numbers this is what you would do

```
void foo(int* a, int *b)
{
    if (*a > *b)
    {
        int temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I don't know why I felt the need to create an array. Thanks!

Comment: You may also want to look at [Simpler way of sorting three numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367745/simpler-way-of-sorting-three-numbers) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare sorted[] as global variable outside of main:

```
int sorted[3];
main()
{
  int a=20, b=15, c=22, sum;
 sum= sumsort(&a,&b,&c);
 printf("%d",sum);
 printf("%d", sorted[0]);
 printf("%d", sorted[1]);
 printf("%d", sorted[2]);

 }
```

And in your function you can use it as shown below:

```
 int sumsort(int *a, int *b, int *c) {

 int sum = *a + *b + *c;

 sorted[0] = *a; 
 sorted[1] = *b;
 sorted[2] = *c;
 for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

   if (sorted[0] > sorted[1]) 

   {
      int temp = sorted[1];
      sorted[1] = sorted[0];
      sorted[0] = temp;
   } // end if
   if (sorted[1] > sorted[2]) 
   {
      int temp2 = sorted[2];
      sorted[2] = sorted[1];
      sorted[1] = temp2;
   } // end if

} // end for

return sum;

} // end sumsort function
```

You may have to check your sorting logic.

Hope this helps :)