# alphabetically sorting multiple strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, if-statement, input, alphabetical

The code I am trying to write must include a prompt from the user, and three separate strings. I am able to get the sorting function to work when I ask the user to input 3 words in the same prompt, but when I separate the inputs out, the sorting function is not working. I am very new to coding (first week), so I apologize if this is not clear.

I am supposed to be writing a series of Python statements that will prompt the user for three strings. Then, using an 'if' statement, print them in alphabetical order.

Here is the code I have so far:
Might anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

```py
word1 = input(str("Please enter a word of your choice:"))
word2 = input(str("please enter another word, but make sure the word does not start with the same letter:"))
word3 = input(str("Awesome! Ok, finally, enter one last word, again making sure not to use the same letter:"))
    
if (word1 == word2):
    print("The words are the same")
else:
    print("Nicely done, you read directions well!")
       
print("The words in alphabetical order are..")
```

What's next here? I can't find this info anywhere.

Comment: In your expression `str("Please...")` the `str` is redundant, because those are already strings.  Nothing to do with your problem, but as you say you're a beginner I thought you might want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the strings and given the comparisons, perform an action. Using the string comparison from [this resource](https://www.journaldev.com/23511/python-string-comparison) to compare strings and the algorithm from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367745/simpler-way-of-sorting-three-numbers/4367793#4367793), you can order the three strings.

```
word1 = input(str("Please enter a word of your choice:"))
word2 = input(str("please enter another word, but make sure the word does not start with the same letter:"))
word3 = input(str("Awesome! Ok, finally, enter one last word, again making sure not to use the same letter:"))

if (word1 == word2):
    print("The words are the same")
else:
    print("Nicely done, you read directions well!")

print("The words in alphabetical order are..")

if(word1>word3):
  tmp = word1
  word1 = word3
  word3 = tmp

if(word1>word2):
  tmp = word1
  word1 = word2
  word2 = tmp

if(word2>word3):
  tmp = word2
  word2 = word3
  word3 = tmp

print(word1)
print(word2)
print(word3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an "if" statement would definitely work for this problem, as mentioned in the other response. However, if you weren't restricted to "if" statements, and for the purpose of learning more about Python, using a list would solve your problem in a neat and easy way. See the code below:

```
word1 = input(str("Please enter a word of your choice:"))
word2 = input(str("please enter another word, but make sure the word does not start with the same letter:"))
word3 = input(str("Awesome! Ok, finally, enter one last word, again making sure not to use the same letter:"))
    
if (word1 == word2 or word1 == word3 or word2 == word3):
    print("The words are the same")
else:
    print("Nicely done, you read directions well!")
       
word_list = [word1, word2, word3]
word_list.sort()

print("The words in alphabetical order are..")
for word in word_list:
    print(word)
```